# Facade implementation implementing an interface

Tags: c#, .net

In books and online examples a "facade" is usually a class that is not implementing and interface. Why is that? Is this the standard for creating a facade?

How would you then write unit tests for it? unless it implements an interface or has virtual methods there is now way to mock it in unit tests.

Comment: It's a question for Programmers, not SO.

Comment: It belongs to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a facade basically is to serve as a wrapper, which can be for a [multitude of reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern#Usage). Hence it is a class, because it encapsulates at least some minimal logic. Interfaces cannot do that.

However, noone is limiting you from implementing an interface on a class which serves the purpose of being a facade. That even makes a *lot* of sense. An interface declares a standardized API, the facade class then serves the purpose of implementing this API for an underlying library / class which needs to be wrapped in order to support that API.